# Could not load file or assembly Accessibility, Version=4.0.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm working on a project, which is used by many users. One of them has sent a letter with such error: "System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly Accessibility, Version=4.0.0.0...". It happens after executing the program, or after 2-3 actions. Nobody has appealed with such problem except him.

The first thing, we have done, was clearing the folder with project in program data folder and reinstalling it, nothing happened.

I've tried to use remote debugger, but couldn't find the exact block, where it happens.

Also I've asked him  to turn off .Net Framework components, restart the computer and turn them on again, but this didn't help.

I think, that there is no needing component on his machine, or some .dll is not found, but I don't know which of them. So I can't even imagine, what file is needed and where should it be placed.

Any ideas?

Comment: It is a local created dll or assembly from GAC?Or imported assembly from Nuget?

Comment: the computers have all the same os 32 bits or 64 bits, not a mixed of them? be sure do not install app 64bits on os 32 bits

Comment: @Frenchy, The app has been on the same OS for a long period o all computers. Last release was in September. So the app has been broken in one moment.

Comment: @So_op, it was my question to you))) I don't know, which file is needed to be checked.

Comment: This assembly lives in the GAC, C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Accessibility directory.  It must never generate a BadImageFormatException, it is an AnyCPU assembly and has no other dependencies.  You must assume that the file is corrupted, only sensible way to recover is to reinstall .net.  When that doesn't work either then reformat the disk drive.

Comment: @Hans Passant, Thank you, I'll try and answer as soon as I can